# find the coefficient

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, summation, binomial-theorem

If $n$ is an odd natural number, and $\sin(n\theta) = \Sigma_{r=0}^{n} b_r \sin^r\theta$, then find $b_r$ in terms of $n$.

I have tried this using trigonometric expansion but unable to find solution for this. Can body help me to solve this trigonometric problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html) is defined as
$$
T_n(\cos \phi) = \cos n \phi
$$
Lets take $\phi = \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta$. Then $\cos \phi = \sin \theta$ and
$$
T_{2k+1}(\sin \theta) = \cos (2k+1) \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta\right) = 
\cos \left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2} - (2k+1) \theta\right) =
\sin \left((2k+1) \theta - k\pi\right) = \\ =(-1)^k \sin (2k+1) \theta.
$$
Finally,
$$
\sin (2k+1) \theta = (-1)^k T_{2k+1}(\sin \theta)
$$

**PS**. Basically, I took expansion of $\sin 3x, \sin 5x, \sin 7x$ and searched for the coefficients in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) and found the sequence [A084930](http://oeis.org/A084930).

Comment: Don't forget that $n$ is an **odd** integer.

Comment: @Scientifica Oh, my bad. I'll edit my post

Comment: Ok. I completely forgot about Chebyshev polynomials! Thanks for reminding me these. I only worked on a problem (exercises) about them in the begining of my freshman year after studying the arithmetic of polynomials.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:** 1) $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\,\sin (x)=\dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ (Euler's Formula).

2) $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,(\cos x+i\sin x)^n=\cos nx+i\sin nx$ (Moivre's Formula). So $\sin nx=\Im\left((\cos x+i\sin x)^n\right)$ where for $z\in\mathbb{C}$, $\Im(z)$ is the imaginary part of $z$.

3) $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{C},\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,(a+b)^n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k}$ (Binomial Theorem).

4) From Euler's formula we have $\sin nx=\dfrac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}} {2}=\dfrac{(e^{ix})^n-(e^{-ix})^n}{2}$ then use Moivre's Formula and the Binomial Theorem to get a sum where you have powers of $\cos$ and $\sin$ and something in term of $i$. Recall that $i=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$. The final formula you should get is:$$\sin n\theta=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\cos^k \theta\sin ^{n-k}\theta\sin\left( \dfrac{n-k}{2}\pi\right)$$

This formula was given by Franciscus Vieta.

Comment: @AshutoshGupta I'm afraid I didn't understand correctly what you said. Could you please clarify what you said?

Comment: But still i got stuck while expanding @Scientifica

Comment: @AjaySharma You're welcome. And yeah I thought this would be enaugh but actually that's not the case at all! I'm going to edit my answer, wait please.

Comment: yup i have done this but this is getting complicated as we furthur proceed @Scientifica

Comment: ?? @AshutoshGupta

Comment: I am getting my answer please help @Scientifica

Comment: @AjaySharma. No worry Aushutosh says Sciectifica answered exactly as required.

Comment: :o AshutoshGupta deleted his commen T_T but seems I understood correctly what he said. THank you @Narasimham

Comment: @AjaySharma I'm going to add a 4th hint. Wait please.

Comment: @AjaySharma I'm done.